# How to delete small cells in tile palette unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Buy code[image]

Currently I want to fire a bullet and when the bullet collides with a small box in the tile palette, that small box will disappear.

I use raycast to check and it works completely correctly, however the return value of cellpos is (0,0,0) and it does not run into this code LevelManager.Instance.CurrentTileMapDestroy.SetTile(cellPos, null) . help me?
[image]